# minimum of a sparse matrix?

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

There does not seem to be a method in scipy.sparse which gives the minimum of a sparse matrix. In particular, I seek the minimum of the columns.

No method appears in the docs and numpy minimum does not apply. If `X` is a sparse matrix, `X.min()` also throws the error: `*** AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'min'`.

Surely this must be something people use. How is this done?

Comment: Presumably you mean "minimum non zero element". After all, a sparse matrix implicitly contains mostly of zeros.

Comment: No -- I mean "minimum". The sparse matrix can have negative entries. larsmans answer gives this.

Comment: A negative entry in a sparse matrix is also non-zero value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With CSR/CSC matrices, use

```
def min_sparse(X):
    if len(X.data) == 0:
        return 0
    m = X.data.min()
    return m if X.getnnz() == X.size else min(m, 0)
```

To do this per row or column, you can `map` this over `X.getrow(i) for i in X.shape[0]` or `X.shape[1]`.

But you're right, this should be a method.

Comment: Thanks -- you're awesome! I will submit to the scipy-list.

Comment: Also -- it's good to know about the attribute .data for sparse matrices. (I believe) this is not mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: Also -- can you explain why you return `m` if `X.getnnz()==X.size` ? I just looked at the actual code and this should always be true.

I see that `m` is what you want to return -- but I don't understand your return logic.

Comment: Also -- there is a slight bug in the code as is.  If X is an empty matrix, X.data is an empty array, and X.data.min() throws an `ValueError`.  Need to add a check for that, but otherwise thanks!